# Setting width or height for graphics in beamer only works with .png?

Tags: latex, beamer, xelatex

This is a problem I had with TexLive 2013 and 2014; working on Mac OS X, 10.8. 
I have to use xelatex or lualatex because of East Asian fonts.

When using picture files with `\includegraphics[settings-for-scaling]{filename}`, I can only use .png files reasonably, JPEGs are always shown in their original size.

I tried this with a minimum beamer document, graphicx package loaded.

Also, I tried several ways to scale (cm, textwidth, etc.). Here are some examples:

Replaced `[settings-for-scaling]` in `\includegraphics[settings-for-scaling]{filename}` with any of the following options:

- `[height=6cm]`, `[height=0.8\textheight]`
- `[width=6cm]`, `[width=0.9\textwidth]`,
- `[height=6cm, width=6cm]`, `[height=0.8\textheight, width=0.9\textwidth]`
- `[keepaspectratio, height=0.8\textheight, width=0.9\textwidth]`

The last solution being preferred for beamer presentations.

I thought it might be a flaw in my settings, but it does not work with the default settings, TexLive installation seems to be OK.

Comment: There should be no problem with this. Note that the `scale` key takes a value, while the `width` and `height` keys expect lengths.

Comment: Should be no problem, yes. I added some examples to be more precise about what does not work.

Comment: Seems to be no longer reproducible with current texlive. If you still experience this problem, please add a [mre] and the corresponding .log file